# Use pipes in R to set data

Tags: r, magrittr

Is it possible to use the pipe Operator in R (not to get) but to set data?

Lets say i want to modify the first row of `mtcars` dataset and set the value of qsec to 99.

Traditional way:

```
mtcars[1, 7] <- 99
```

Is that also possible using the pipe Operator?

```
mtcars %>% filter(qsec == 16.46) %>% select(qsec) <- 99
```

Comment: `mtcars %>% mutate(qsec = replace(qsec, 1, 99))`

Comment: I'd stick with base R for this because it's a pain to retain the row names with `dplyr`

Comment: you are Right. it would be sthg along `mtcars %>% mutate(qsec = replace(qsec, which(.$qsec == 16.46), 99))` and thats not really more readable than base R, i guess,....

Comment: You say this `mtcars[mtcars$qsec==16.46,"qsec"] <- 99` is not easy to read?

Comment: its more readable than the dplyr Version imho.

Answer (score 3):

If we are in a state where the chain is absolute necessary or curious to know whether `<-` can be applied in a chain

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>% 
    `[<-`(1, 7, 99) %>%
     head(2)
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 99.00  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Also, `inset` (from the comments) is an alias for `[<-`

```
mtcars %>% 
   inset(1, 7, 99) %>%
   head(2)
```

Comment: if you attach magrittr as you did here you can use `inset()`